# How do I adjust font size for page titles in Firefox URL bar drop down?

Tags: windows, firefox, fonts, user-interface

Something went wrong and here's how my Firefox URL bar dropdown looks like (underlined by me):

[image]

Note that page titles (such as *Super User*) are set in font larger than that of the URL. I remember they were of same size before it "went wrong".

I tried various userChrome.css adjustments including this one

```
#urlbar .autocomplete-richlistitem {
    font-size: 10pt
}
```

but nothing seems to work.

I want to make size of fonts used for titles (such as *Super User*) smaller. How do I do that?

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: @Run5k Nope, because there're no obvious adjustments to made.

Comment: We are always glad to help, but that is actually the first time you have provided us with feedback.  Could you please elaborate on that statement?

Answer (score 0):

I am rather certain that this is the default behavior.  As a result, this isn't really a case where *"something went wrong"*.

In a default Firefox configuration, anything you type within the address bar (a.k.a. URL bar) is going to be the focus of the search criteria, including a page title like **superuser.com** in your example.

That being said, you can change that default search criteria through the following procedure:

[image: Firefox Location Bar]

([Source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/awesome-bar-search-firefox-bookmarks-history-tabs))

Try adjusting the settings for `History`, `Bookmarks`, `Open Tabs`, and `Search Engine Suggestions` to see if you find a preferable effect.